# Running several Python scripts with from one function

Tags: python

I have a few .py programs I run in my IDE separately (I guess they just run as separate processes, right). Each of them has a couple of classes, some global variables etc and the main function. How can I achieve the same effect programmatically, i.e. run these scripts in particular order?

I've tried several methods, but they didn't seem to give the same effect as starting those scripts 'by hand'.

Comment: Check out the `subprocess` module.

Comment: What are the things you tried?

Comment: I've tried Popen from `subprocess`, but I can't really figure out how to use it. It might be a problem. Oh, and I'm on Windows.

Comment: is running the main function protected in the script? i.e. there is a line in the script `if __name__ == "__main__":` ? If so you could to import and run the suite of protected commands manually.

Comment: You can have a Python script that imports the different scripts main method with different names *From script_1 import main as main_1* or *import script1* *script_1.main* and calls them in his own main method with threads for example or easier create a shell script that runs the commands to run the scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried writing an additional script that imports what's needed from these separate programs and runs them in the manner that you designate?

Answer (score 0):

You could make a third script which contains the name of all the other scripts that you wish to run, and then give a `subprocess` command call to `python`
Learn more about subprocess [here](http://pymotw.com/2/subprocess/)

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, importing a script will run the script. If I have some script called `spam.py` that reads:

```
print 'eggs'
```

Then I can write another script `run.py` in the same directory with the following:

```
import spam
```

When I run a `python run.py`, it will output 'eggs'.

Most scripts that are used as library modules that you import just contain function and class definitions. These modules are still run when you import them, but they don't actually do anything other than to make the definitions.

So if I change `spam.py` to read:

```
def main():
    print 'eggs'
```

Then when I run `python run.py` nothing will actually happen. But I can change `run.py` to read as follows:

```
import spam
spam.main()
```

Now it will define `main` in the namespace `spam`, and by calling `main()` I print 'eggs'.

Finally, sometimes scripts are meant to be both used as modules to be imported and scripts to be run on their own. For this it is often the case that when imported you don't want the script to do anything besides define modules and classes. You can make `spam.py` work this way as follows:

```
def main():
    print 'eggs'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Now if you run `python spam.py` it will print 'eggs' to the screen. But if you `import spam` it will not. The suite of statements inside `if __name__ == '__main__':` is only run if you call the script directly.

However, you can still get the same behavior from `spam` as doing `python spam.py` by importing `spam` and calling `main`:

```
import spam
spam.main()
```

Again, this prints eggs to the screen.

So if you have a number of scripts `foo.py`, `bar.py`, `baz.py` that you want to run in sequence from another script, you just import all of the scripts and then if any commands are protected by `if __name__ == '__main__':`, you run them in your calling script making sure to prepend the appropriate namespace to each command (i.e. if `main()` is called in `foo.py`, then you call `foo.main()`).

Comment: Even though `spam.py` has no 'main' method, it will be created automatically by calling `import spam
spam.main()` from `run.py`? If I called `foo` instead of `main` there, it wouldn't be created, right? Anyway, the problem is I can't run them the way you described, because almost every script contains an infinite loop (that's why I'm running them manually, separately). It won't run the second script before it finishes executing the first one, and it will never happen (infinite loop).

Comment: No - maybe my explanation was not clear enough. Nothing will automatically be created. If there was a `def main():` in spam.py, and you `import spam`, then you can run it as `spam.main()`.